# Having advance intellisense for custom routines

Tags: matlab, intellisense

When typing some well-know routine in command window, matlab provides some helper to indicate for the various syntaxes. For instance `hist` routine is defined as:

```
function [] = hist(varargin)
%[
    % ... %
%]
end
```

And typing in command window shows the following:

[image]

Is it possible to do the same for custom functions ?

For instance, and obviously without further information, following dummy routine:

```
function [] = myfunc(varargin)
%[
%]
end
```

Only shows:

[image]

I searched for `xbins` term in matlab installation folders but it is only referenced in the documentation file `~\help\matlab\ref\hist.html`.

Do you think Matlab is relying on this html file to provide intellisense or is the syntax helper hard-coded for well-known routines only ?

Comment: The function syntax hints are indeed taken from the 'Syntax' section of an HTML help page for the function, not the inline documentation. It's discussed briefly in the comments section of [this Undocumented MATLAB post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-desktop-tab-completions) but info on formatting the documents appropriately seems to be lacking. A good starting point would be to just look at what already exists and copy appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for this link. So far I suits my needs, can you please turn your comment into an answer so I can validate it ?